# capistrano is not logging with ssh key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, capistrano

I keep getting this error:

Authentication failed for user deploy@179.92.100.40

```
  set :stage, :test
    server '179.92.100.40', port: 25000, user: 'deploy'
    set :branch, "dev"
    set :deploy_to, "/srv/www/test"
    set :format,        :pretty
    set :log_level,     :debug
    set :keep_releases, 5

    set :repo_url, "https://donatas@bitbucket.org/test.git"
    set :scm, :git
    set :git_strategy, SubmoduleStrategy

    set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w('/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'), auth_methods: %w(publickey) }
```

I have added local id_rsa.pub to remotes machines authorized_keys so that if I type something like this in the local machine:

```
 cat id_rsa.pub | ssh deploy@179.92.100.40 -p 25000  "mkdir -p /home/deploy/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

So, now in the local machine if I run something like this:

```
ssh deploy@179.92.100.40 -p 25000 'hostname; uptime'
```

I get the result of those commands without typing password, but with capistrano I can not login with ssh. It works fine with the password though.

Answer (score 0):

None of those `:ssh_options` should be necessary, and in fact they may be counterproductive. For example, unless you are setting the `:user` variable someplace else you haven't shown, then `fetch(:user)` will be `nil`, which is not what you want.

Can you just delete the entire `:ssh_options` and try again?